# Repeat rows weekly based on start and end date

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I have a bus plan (table) with bus routes, weekday, direction, startdate and enddate.

I need to do a select that gives me all the individual depatures: all the correct weekday (inclusive) inbetween start and enddates (repeat is the number of repeats between the two dates).

So for the two top lines in this table (the table is much longer):

[image: Original table]

| Route | Season | Weekday | Direction | Startdate | Enddate | repeat |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 107 | W23 | Saturday | Arrival | 05-11-2022 | 05-11-2022 | 1 |
| 107 | W23 | Sunday | Arrival | 30-11-2022 | 05-11-2022 | 2 |

I need the output to be

[image: Desired result]

| Route | Season | Weekday | Direction | Startdate | Enddate | Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 107 | W23 | Saturday | Arrival | 05-11-2022 | 05-11-2022 | 05-11-2022 |
| 107 | W23 | Sunday | Arrival | 30-10-2022 | 05-11-2022 | 30-10-2022 |
| 107 | W23 | Sunday | Arrival | 30-10-2022 | 05-11-2022 | 05-11-2022 |

Several lines can share the same date so it is not as simple as creating a calender and fill out the dates with the appropriate departures/arrivals, since more than one departure and arrival will take place each day.

Is this doable?

Comment: please do not post image, post the sample data and expected data as text

Comment: On your question, yes. it is doable. Make use of [tally table](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4176/the-sql-server-numbers-table-explained-part-1/)